# jquery checking or matching text within a url string?

Tags: php, jquery, regex, preg-match, match

Is there a way to get a certain string of text inside a url string?

example:

I would like to see if this url has clear.jpg or just the simple word clear

if `http://www.somesite.com/clear.jpg` or `http://www.clearsomething.com/`

I wanted to see if these url can pass through a check if they have clear in them.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this server side or client side?

Answer (score 2):

Use the javascript function substr() to check if it ends with "jpg". Like:

```
if (url.substr(-3) == "jpg") {}
```

Or if you want to check the existance in a string:

```
var pattern = /clear.jpg/g
pattern.test(url);
```

Comment: how come we're checking jpg? i'm checking the text clear, or any text for futer reference

Comment: Well, just put in whatever you want to check it against. I thought you meant to figure out whether the url ended with clear.jpg or not...